# dcast not retaining variable type as character, error in vapply when a variable is NA

Tags: r, reshape2, dcast

In attempting to reshape data using `resphape2::dcast`, I am encountering an error involving `NA` entries. Sample data are at the end.

The data are reshaped from long to wide, but on occasion some parameters have all `NA` entries, which appears to be causing the issue. Or at least, I think it is. If I remove any parameter like that, `Ammonia` in this example, the error goes away.

In debugging `dcast`, it seems to pin down to this line:

```
ordered <- vaggregate(.value = value, .group = overall, 
  .fun = fun.aggregate, ..., .default = fill, .n = n)
```

which results in the error:

```
Error in vapply(indices, fun, .default) : 
values must be type 'character',
but FUN(X[[1]]) result is type 'integer'
```

Seeing that the `NA` variable is first in line, I thought the `aggregate` function may default to integer, even though the entire column is `character`, but moving those rows did not solve it. The only way I can find to [solve it is by using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32931473/how-to-avoid-na-columns-in-dcast-output) `na.omit`, which removes that parameter completely. My expected output would retain any parameters with all `NA` if possible. The second reason for this is if a day/depth is not sampled, it should be retained and those entries should be `ns` (not sampled). **Is there a way I can solve this error without having to remove all `NA` parameters that will be reshaped?**

Reproducible example (data are below `dcast` code):

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(df, station + date + depth ~ parmcode, value.var = "value_qualif", fill="ns")

dcast(na.omit(df), station + date + depth ~ parmcode,
 value.var = "value_qualif", fill="ns") # solves error, but removes parameter completely
```

Example data:

```
df <- structure(list(station = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"), date = c("7/2/2018", 
"7/2/2018", "7/2/2018", "7/2/2018", "7/2/2018", "7/2/2018", "7/2/2018", 
"7/2/2018", "7/2/2018", "7/2/2018", "7/2/2018", "7/2/2018", "7/2/2018", 
"7/2/2018", "7/2/2018", "7/2/2018", "7/2/2018", "7/2/2018", "7/2/2018", 
"7/2/2018", "7/2/2018", "7/2/2018", "7/2/2018", "7/2/2018", "7/2/2018", 
"7/2/2018", "7/2/2018", "7/2/2018", "7/2/2018", "7/2/2018", "7/1/2018", 
"7/1/2018", "7/1/2018", "7/1/2018", "7/1/2018", "7/1/2018", "7/1/2018", 
"7/1/2018", "7/1/2018", "7/9/2018", "7/9/2018", "7/9/2018", "7/9/2018", 
"7/9/2018", "7/9/2018", "7/9/2018", "7/9/2018", "7/9/2018", "7/9/2018", 
"7/9/2018", "7/9/2018", "7/9/2018", "7/9/2018", "7/9/2018", "7/9/2018", 
"7/9/2018", "7/9/2018", "7/9/2018", "7/9/2018", "7/9/2018", "7/9/2018", 
"7/9/2018", "7/9/2018", "7/9/2018", "7/9/2018", "7/9/2018", "7/9/2018", 
"7/9/2018", "7/9/2018"), depth = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L), parmcode = c("CDOM", 
"DENSITY", "DO", "ENTERO", "PH", "TOTAL", "XMS", "TEMP", "SAL", 
"FECAL", "TOTAL", "FECAL", "ENTERO", "CDOM", "XMS", "TEMP", "SAL", 
"PH", "DO", "DENSITY", "DO", "DENSITY", "TOTAL", "FECAL", "PH", 
"CDOM", "XMS", "TEMP", "SAL", "ENTERO", "AMMONIA AS N", "AMMONIA AS N", 
"AMMONIA AS N", "AMMONIA AS N", "AMMONIA AS N", "AMMONIA AS N", 
"AMMONIA AS N", "AMMONIA AS N", "AMMONIA AS N", "TOTAL", "XMS", 
"TEMP", "SAL", "PH", "DO", "DENSITY", "CDOM", "FECAL", "ENTERO", 
"CDOM", "FECAL", "ENTERO", "PH", "DO", "TEMP", "XMS", "TOTAL", 
"DENSITY", "SAL", "TOTAL", "FECAL", "ENTERO", "XMS", "TEMP", 
"SAL", "PH", "DO", "DENSITY", "CDOM"), value_qualif = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "<2", "<2", "<2", "1.3", "69.67", 
"16.6", "33.7", "8.1", "7.6", "24.622", "5.5", "25.279", "<2", 
"<2", "7.8", "1.38", "72.96", "13.2", "33.61", "<2", NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "<2", "77.82", "20.8", "33.72", "8.2", 
"8.8", "23.58", "1.01", "<2", "<2", "1.78", "<2", "<2", "8", 
"6.5", "13.5", "67.19", "2e", "25.197", "33.58", "2e", "2e", 
"<2", "75.53", "12.9", "33.61", "7.9", "5.5", "25.34", "1.77"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -69L))
```

Some tangentially related questions that don't answer my question are [POSIXct values become numeric in reshape2 dcast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12289731/posixct-values-become-numeric-in-reshape2-dcast) and [Error with custom aggregate function for a cast() call in R reshape2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835202/error-with-custom-aggregate-function-for-a-cast-call-in-r-reshape2)

With using `na.omit` my output is:

```
  station     date depth CDOM DENSITY  DO ENTERO FECAL  PH   SAL TEMP TOTAL   XMS
1       A 7/2/2018    12  1.3  24.622 7.6     <2    <2 8.1  33.7 16.6    <2 69.67
2       A 7/2/2018    18 1.38  25.279 5.5     <2    <2 7.8 33.61 13.2    <2 72.96
3       A 7/9/2018     1 1.01   23.58 8.8     <2    <2 8.2 33.72 20.8    <2 77.82
4       A 7/9/2018    12 1.78  25.197 6.5     <2    <2   8 33.58 13.5    2e 67.19
5       A 7/9/2018    18 1.77   25.34 5.5     <2    2e 7.9 33.61 12.9    2e 75.53
```

Expected output without using `na.omit` is:

```
  station     date depth AMMONIA CDOM  DENSITY  DO  ENTERO FECAL  PH   SAL TEMP TOTAL   XMS
1       A 7/2/2018     1    ns    ns      ns    ns     ns    ns   ns    ns   ns    ns    ns
2       A 7/2/2018    12    ns    1.3   24.622  7.6    <2    <2  8.1  33.7 16.6    <2 69.67
3       A 7/2/2018    18    ns    1.38  25.279  5.5    <2    <2  7.8 33.61 13.2    <2 72.96
4       A 7/9/2018     1    ns    1.01  23.58   8.8    <2    <2  8.2 33.72 20.8    <2 77.82
5       A 7/9/2018    12    ns    1.78  25.197  6.5    <2    <2    8 33.58 13.5    2e 67.19
6       A 7/9/2018    18    ns    1.77  25.34   5.5    <2    2e  7.9 33.61 12.9    2e 75.53
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual issue is that all the parameters have only one value for each triple of (station, date, depth) *except* for `AMMONIA AS N`, which has three `NA` entries.

For instance,

```
dcast(df, station + date + depth ~ parmcode, value.var = "value_qualif")
# Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length
#   station     date depth AMMONIA AS N CDOM DENSITY DO ENTERO FECAL PH SAL TEMP TOTAL XMS
# 1       A 7/1/2018     1            3    0       0  0      0     0  0   0    0     0   0
# 2       A 7/1/2018    12            3    0       0  0      0     0  0   0    0     0   0
# 3       A 7/1/2018    18            3    0       0  0      0     0  0   0    0     0   0
# 4       A 7/2/2018     1            0    1       1  1      1     1  1   1    1     1   1
# 5       A 7/2/2018    12            0    1       1  1      1     1  1   1    1     1   1
# 6       A 7/2/2018    18            0    1       1  1      1     1  1   1    1     1   1
# 7       A 7/9/2018     1            0    1       1  1      1     1  1   1    1     1   1
# 8       A 7/9/2018    12            0    1       1  1      1     1  1   1    1     1   1
# 9       A 7/9/2018    18            0    1       1  1      1     1  1   1    1     1   1
```

Once we remove the duplicate rows everything works smoothly

```
dcast(df[!duplicated(df), ], station + date + depth ~ parmcode, value.var = "value_qualif")
#   station     date depth AMMONIA AS N CDOM DENSITY   DO ENTERO FECAL   PH   SAL TEMP TOTAL   XMS
# 1       A 7/1/2018     1         <NA> <NA>    <NA> <NA>   <NA>  <NA> <NA>  <NA> <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
# 2       A 7/1/2018    12         <NA> <NA>    <NA> <NA>   <NA>  <NA> <NA>  <NA> <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
# 3       A 7/1/2018    18         <NA> <NA>    <NA> <NA>   <NA>  <NA> <NA>  <NA> <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
# 4       A 7/2/2018     1         <NA> <NA>    <NA> <NA>   <NA>  <NA> <NA>  <NA> <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
# 5       A 7/2/2018    12         <NA>  1.3  24.622  7.6     <2    <2  8.1  33.7 16.6    <2 69.67
# 6       A 7/2/2018    18         <NA> 1.38  25.279  5.5     <2    <2  7.8 33.61 13.2    <2 72.96
# 7       A 7/9/2018     1         <NA> 1.01   23.58  8.8     <2    <2  8.2 33.72 20.8    <2 77.82
# 8       A 7/9/2018    12         <NA> 1.78  25.197  6.5     <2    <2    8 33.58 13.5    2e 67.19
# 9       A 7/9/2018    18         <NA> 1.77   25.34  5.5     <2    2e  7.9 33.61 12.9    2e 75.53

dcast(df[!duplicated(df), ], station + date + depth ~ parmcode, value.var = "value_qualif", fill = "ns")
#   station     date depth AMMONIA AS N CDOM DENSITY  DO ENTERO FECAL  PH   SAL TEMP TOTAL   XMS
# 1       A 7/1/2018     1           ns   ns      ns  ns     ns    ns  ns    ns   ns    ns    ns
# 2       A 7/1/2018    12           ns   ns      ns  ns     ns    ns  ns    ns   ns    ns    ns
# 3       A 7/1/2018    18           ns   ns      ns  ns     ns    ns  ns    ns   ns    ns    ns
# 4       A 7/2/2018     1           ns   ns      ns  ns     ns    ns  ns    ns   ns    ns    ns
# 5       A 7/2/2018    12           ns  1.3  24.622 7.6     <2    <2 8.1  33.7 16.6    <2 69.67
# 6       A 7/2/2018    18           ns 1.38  25.279 5.5     <2    <2 7.8 33.61 13.2    <2 72.96
# 7       A 7/9/2018     1           ns 1.01   23.58 8.8     <2    <2 8.2 33.72 20.8    <2 77.82
# 8       A 7/9/2018    12           ns 1.78  25.197 6.5     <2    <2   8 33.58 13.5    2e 67.19
# 9       A 7/9/2018    18           ns 1.77   25.34 5.5     <2    2e 7.9 33.61 12.9    2e 75.53
```

Alternatively, you could run

```
dcast(df, station + date + depth ~ parmcode, value.var = "value_qualif", 
      fill = NA_character_, fun.aggregate = head, n = 1)
#   station     date depth AMMONIA AS N CDOM DENSITY   DO ENTERO FECAL   PH   SAL TEMP TOTAL   XMS
# 1       A 7/1/2018     1         <NA> <NA>    <NA> <NA>   <NA>  <NA> <NA>  <NA> <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
# 2       A 7/1/2018    12         <NA> <NA>    <NA> <NA>   <NA>  <NA> <NA>  <NA> <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
# 3       A 7/1/2018    18         <NA> <NA>    <NA> <NA>   <NA>  <NA> <NA>  <NA> <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
# 4       A 7/2/2018     1         <NA> <NA>    <NA> <NA>   <NA>  <NA> <NA>  <NA> <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
# 5       A 7/2/2018    12         <NA>  1.3  24.622  7.6     <2    <2  8.1  33.7 16.6    <2 69.67
# 6       A 7/2/2018    18         <NA> 1.38  25.279  5.5     <2    <2  7.8 33.61 13.2    <2 72.96
# 7       A 7/9/2018     1         <NA> 1.01   23.58  8.8     <2    <2  8.2 33.72 20.8    <2 77.82
# 8       A 7/9/2018    12         <NA> 1.78  25.197  6.5     <2    <2    8 33.58 13.5    2e 67.19
# 9       A 7/9/2018    18         <NA> 1.77   25.34  5.5     <2    2e  7.9 33.61 12.9    2e 75.53
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22624915/1320535) regarding `NA_character_`.

Comment: I see now, those may be sampled in triplicate. This was the inverse of what I thought was wrong. I had to modify the `duplicate` call since I have unique sample IDs for those duplicates in my actual data, but this did the trick.